# how to login into to a multiple website url using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

1. read the URL list and enter the ID/Password.
2. By URL, input form has different xpaths.
3. read url and check xpath to input id/pw,

but the error occurred. 
I also want to know what optimization is.

```
'''

def csv_reader(url_obj):
        reader = csv.DictReader(url_obj, delimiter=',')
        for line in reader:
            print(line["SN"],line["Title"],line["URL"]),
            URL = line["URL"]
            site = line["Title"]
            browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
            browser.get(URL)
            time.sleep(3)
            # First url input part
            if browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="id"]"""):
                browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="id"]""").send_keys("test")
                time.sleep(3)
            # Seconds url input part
            elif browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="uid"]"""):
                 browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="uid"]""").send_keys("test")
                 time.sleep(3)
            else :
                pass
```

My results are as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\source\se.py", line 63, in 
    csv_reader(url_obj)
  File "C:\source\se.py", line 31, in csv_reader
    if browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="id"]"""):
  File "C:\Users\m4gic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\m4gic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\m4gic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\m4gic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="id"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using if and else for multiple URL's, in that case if URL list increases you will have to write infinite if and else.

You can have xpath written in csv file as well for different URL and I believe it will be different for all the URL's :

**Sample code :**

```
def csv_reader(url_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(url_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        print(line["SN"], line["Title"], line["URL"]),
        URL = line["URL"]
        site = line["Title"]
        xpath = line["Xpath"]
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
        browser.get(URL)
        time.sleep(3)
        # First url input part
        if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"{xpath}") > 0 :
            browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"{xpath}").send_keys("test")
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: thx sir.. We have a lot of url and we need automation. I am looking for an effective way.Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: CSV or excel should be good enough to maintain URLS